# C++ function pointer (class member) to non-static member function

Tags: c++, function-pointers

```
class Foo {
public:
    Foo() { do_something = &Foo::func_x; }

    int (Foo::*do_something)(int);   // function pointer to class member function

    void setFunc(bool e) { do_something = e ? &Foo::func_x : &Foo::func_y; }

private:
    int func_x(int m) { return m *= 5; }
    int func_y(int n) { return n *= 6; }
};

int
main()
{
    Foo f;
    f.setFunc(false);
    return (f.*do_something)(5);  // <- Not ok. Compile error.
}
```

How can I get this to work?

Comment: Aren't `func_x` and `func_y` static functions even though they're not marked as such?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The line you want is

```
   return (f.*f.do_something)(5);
```

(That compiles -- I've tried it)

"`*f.do_something`" refers to the pointer itself --- "f" tells us where to get the do_something value *from*.  But we still need to give an object that will be the this pointer when we call the function.  That's why we need the "`f.`" prefix.

Comment: Technically, "f.do_something" returns the pointer, and the ".*" operator calls the pointer-to-member function on a class.

Comment: So I assume `return (f.*Foo::do_something)(5)` should also work.

Comment: @ThomasMcLeod It does not.

Comment: Ah, but this means that if you have `Foo g`, then this would also compile and run: `return (g.*f.do_something)(5);`  Right? (even if there's no good reason to do that)

Comment: @ThomasMcLeod no, because `Foo::do_something` names the data member of the class. You need an instance to access a non-static data member.

Comment: @Caleth, correct. This is sever years old but I think I misunderstood the question the first time.

Answer (score 36):

```
 class A{
    public:
        typedef int (A::*method)();

        method p;
        A(){
            p = &A::foo;
            (this->*p)(); // <- trick 1, inner call
        }

        int foo(){
            printf("foo\n");
            return 0;
        }
    };

    void main()
    {
        A a;
        (a.*a.p)(); // <- trick 2, outer call
    }
```

Comment: Tudok, after going through your post a second time I realized that you have given the right answer too (trick 2). Thanks.

Comment: Your code does not work. I copy/paste and try compile.  test_function_pointer_2.C: In constructor 'A::A()':
test_function_pointer_2.C:7: error: argument of type 'int (A::)()' does not match 'int (A::*)()'

Comment: @user180574, I remember that it did work. Anyway, you're right. I tested it with gcc and got the same error. I fixed it.

Answer (score 3):

```
class A {
    int var;
    int var2;
public:
    void setVar(int v);
    int getVar();
    void setVar2(int v);
    int getVar2();
    typedef int (A::*_fVar)();
    _fVar fvar;
    void setFvar(_fVar afvar) { fvar = afvar; }
    void insideCall() { (this->*fvar)(); }
};

void A::setVar(int v)
{
    var = v;
}

int A::getVar()
{
    std::cout << "A::getVar() is called. var = " << var << std::endl;
    return var;
}

void A::setVar2(int v2)
{
    var2 = v2;
}

int A::getVar2()
{
    std::cout << "A::getVar2() is called. var2 = " << var2 << std::endl;
    return var2;
}

int main()
{
    A a;
    a.setVar(3);
    a.setVar2(5);

//    a.fvar = &A::getVar;
    a.setFvar(&A::getVar);
    (a.*a.fvar)();

    a.setFvar(&A::getVar2);
    (a.*a.fvar)();

    a.setFvar(&A::getVar);
    a.insideCall();

    a.setFvar(&A::getVar2);
    a.insideCall();

    return 0;
}
```

I extended Nick Dandoulakis's answer. Thank you.

I added a function which set the member function pointer from outside of the class. I added another function which can be called from outside to show inner call of member function pointer.

Comment: Rather than only post a block of code, please *explain* why this code solves the problem posed. Without an explanation, this is not an answer.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I wrote that it is extended from Nick Dandoulakis answer. It was explained in there. I am new in stackoverflow maybe I need to do in a different way.

Comment: Well, you could explain what you changed, for example, and why.

Answer (score 0):

Try (f.*do_something)(5);

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class A {

public:
    void hello()
    {
        cout << "hello" << endl;
    };

    int x = 0;

};


void main(void)
{

    //pointer
    A * a = new A;
    void(A::*pfun)() = &A::hello;
    int  A::*v1 = &A::x;

    (a->*pfun)();
    a->*v1 = 100;
    cout << a->*v1 << endl << endl;

    //----------------------------- 
    A  b;
    void(A::*fun)() = &A::hello;
    int  A::*v2 = &A::x;

    (b.*fun)();
    b.*v2 = 200;
    cout << b.*v2 << endl;

}
```

Answer (score -4):

I think calling a non static member of the class could also be done using a static member function.

Comment: This is not possible. "When modifying a data member in a class declaration, the static keyword specifies that one copy of the member is shared by all instances of the class. When modifying a member function in a class declaration, **the static keyword specifies that the function accesses only static members**." See [MSDN reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1sb61xd(v=vs.80).aspx)

Comment: well, you could keep a list of all instances trough the constructor and then call it for all instances, but i guess that is somewhat of a whack idea :p