# Calling C++ member function pointer from a struct

Tags: c++, function-pointers

I have found information on calling C++ member function pointers and calling pointers in structs, but I need to call a member function pointer that exists inside of a structure, and I have not been able to get the syntax correct.  I have the following snippet inside a method in class MyClass:

```
void MyClass::run() {
    struct {
        int (MyClass::*command)(int a, int b);
        int id;
    } functionMap[] = {
        {&MyClass::commandRead,  1},
        {&MyClass::commandWrite, 2},
    };

    (functionMap[0].MyClass::*command)(x, y);
}

int MyClass::commandRead(int a, int b) {
    ...
}

int MyClass::commandWrite(int a, int b) {
    ...
}
```

This gives me:

```
error: expected unqualified-id before '*' token
error: 'command' was not declared in this scope
(referring to the line '(functionMap[0].MyClass::*command)(x, y);')
```

Moving those parenthesis around results in syntax errors recommending using .* or ->* neither of which work in this situation.  Does anyone know the proper syntax?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/990625/c-function-pointer-class-member-to-non-static-member-function seems related to this question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use:

```
(this->*functionMap[0].command)(x, y);
```

Tested and compiles ;)

Comment: Ah perfect!  Thanks for the response, and the above answer provides the reasoning.

Answer (score 5):

I haven't compiled any code, but just from looking at it I can see you're missing a few things.

- Remove the `MyClass::` from where you call the function pointer.
- Need to pass the `this` pointer to the functions (if they use any instance data), so that means you need an instance of `MyClass` to call it.

(After a bit of research) It looks like you need to do something like this (also thanks to @VoidStar):

```
(this->*(functionMap[0].command)(x, y));
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  The below answer works (with the parenthesis including 'this' instead of 'functionMap'.  Thank you for the response.

Comment: I wasn't sure exactly if it required those or not. Though for that problem I would probably try a different solution, such as just using an if, or if more flexibility is required some sort of Command pattern.