# Classes and void pointers

Tags: c++, void-pointers

I have the following header:

```
class MyClass {
private:
    static void (*OnRequest)();
    static void (*OnReceive)(int numBytes);

public:
    MyClass();

    static void SetOnReceive(void (*function)(int));
    static void SetOnRequest(void (*function)(void));    

};

void NonClassFunction();
```

and the following declaration:

```
#include "MyClass.h"
MyClass::MyClass() {
...
}

void MyClass::SetOnReceive(void (*function)(int) ) {
    OnReceive = function;
}

void MyClass::SetOnRequest( void (*function)(void) ) {
    OnRequest = function;
}

void NonClassFunction() {
    MyClass::OnRequest();
}
```

The code compiles fine but I get the following errors when I link:

> unresolved symbol MyClass::OnReceive, first referenced in ./src/MyClass.obj
>   unresolved symbol MyClass::OnRequest, first referenced in ./src/MyClass.obj

I need OnRequest and OnReceive to function like a callback through NonClassFunction(). The NonClassFunction is being called by an interrupt so there is a bit of object oriented mangling going on here.  MyClass is designed to be inherited.  Ideally I would like OnRequest and OnReceive to be virtual but you cannot make static methods virtual.

Comment: From the comp.lang.c++ FAQ: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/link-errs-static-data-mems.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are linker error, which means the members are **not** *defined*. They're only *declared*.

The pointer members are `static` members, so they need definition, which is outside the class.

Do this in the `.cpp` file:

```
void (*MyClass::OnRequest)();
void (*MyClass::OnReceive)(int);
```

These are *definitions*, and what you've written in the class are only declarations.

Note the position of `*` in the above definitions. A slight mistake such as these:

```
void (MyClass::*OnRequest)();    //notice the difference
void (MyClass::*OnReceive)(int); //notice the difference
```

would change the meaning completely! Now these are *pointers-to-non-static-member-function*. So know the difference and be careful. :-)

Comment: Thanks.  I tried something closer to what you said not to do void MyClass::(*OnRequest)(); and it would not compile.  I tried what you said to do and it worked perfectly.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

These two variables in your header:

```
static void (*OnRequest)();
static void (*OnReceive)(int numBytes);
```

Have not been defined.

Define them in your cpp file.

```
void (*MyClass::OnRequest)();
void (*MyClass::OnReceive)(int);
```

Answer (score 1):

You provided the declarations of the function pointers, but not the definition. Add this to a single cpp file:

```
void (*MyClass::OnRequest)();
void (*MyClass::OnReceive)(int);
```

Answer (score 0):

i asked the same question recently
[how-to-send-a-message-to-the-class-that-created-the-object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13787181/how-to-send-a-message-to-the-class-that-created-the-object)

```
enemies_array[0].enemy =  new Enemy(this,&Game::EnemyEvent);   

typedef void (Game::*ChangeFunc)(DWORD &)
Class Enemy
{
private:
   ChangeFunc iChange;
   Game *pGame;
}:

Enemy(Game *pCreatorGame, ChangeFunc iChangeHandler )
{
    iChange = iChangeHandler;
    pGame = pCreatorGame;
}

void Enemy::Draw(D3DGraphics& gfx)
{
    (pGame->*iChange)(this->dwThreadID);
```