# Is this a new method to get address of any function member?

Tags: c++, function, structure, member

**"Member function"** is the most stubborn thing. Simply I cannot convert them into `*void` values. I've done some methods which can solve this; however, the only thing I annoyed: I have to create a new definition for every set of argument types. So the fastest method to achieve the goal :

```
struct FOO{

    void ONE_PARAM(int){}
    void TWO_PARAM(int, int){}
    void THREE_PARAM(int, int, int){}
    void FOUR_PARAM(int, int, int, int){}
};
```

Firstly, calling a structure function member by assembly :

```
__asm mov ecx, ADDRESS_OF_STRUCTURE
__asm push //parameters
__asm call ADDRESS_OF_MEMBER_FUNCTION
```

**Longest : Template...**

```
template <class F,void (F::*Function)(int)>   //Note : Only for FOO::ONE_PARAM
void * GetFunctionAddress() {

    union ADDRESS  
    { 
        void (F::*func)(int);  
        void * function_address;  
    }address_data;  

    address_data.func = Function;  
    return address_data.function_address; 
}
```

**Shorter method : Define a function pointer to member function**

```
void *function_address;
///////////////////////////////////////////////
void(FOO::*address_ONE_PARAM)(int) = FOO::ONE_PARAM;
void(FOO::*address_TWO_PARAM)(int, int) = FOO::TWO_PARAM;
void(FOO::*address_THREE_PARAM)(int, int, int) = FOO::THREE_PARAM;
void(FOO::*address_FOUR_PARAM)(int, int, int, int) = FOO::FOUR_PARAM;

__asm mov eax, address_ONE_PARAM //OK
__asm mov function_address, eax

__asm mov eax, address_TWO_PARAM //OK
__asm mov function_address, eax

__asm mov eax, address_THREE_PARAM //OK
__asm mov function_address, eax

__asm mov eax, address_FOUR_PARAM //OK
__asm mov function_address, eax
```

But it's still too long.

**The most convenient method** : Using directly standard function : **sprintf**

I discovered **__thiscall** functions also can be pushed as **"..." parameters** and I have checked it carefully by function **printf**. It is simple, and you don't need to define again its whole set of argument types to accept the pointer. And the code :

```
unsigned int address;
char buffer[12];
///////////////////////////////////////////////
sprintf(buffer, "0x%X", FOO::ONE_PARAM);
address = strtol(buffer,NULL,16);

sprintf(buffer, "0x%X", FOO::TWO_PARAM);
address = strtol(buffer,NULL,16);

sprintf(buffer, "0x%X", FOO::THREE_PARAM);
address = strtol(buffer,NULL,16);

sprintf(buffer, "0x%X", FOO::FOUR_PARAM);
address = strtol(buffer,NULL,16);
```

As you can see this method is much shorter and also it's very convenient. I don't need to insert assembly code, the code looks better but on the other hand, I am worrying about speed. Can the code be compressed more? Suppose two commands now it only requires a single command to work, is this possible?

Comment: By "function member" do you mean "member function"?

Comment: Why do you need to convert the function address to void*?

Comment: Member functions are not functions. (E.g. you cannot *call* a member function.) It is unreasonable to even *expect* that they should have an address in the classic sense.

Comment: I am building up a function library, and I will use its database to call a function by assembly... And "member function" : I will pick a proper structure, move its address to ecx and then call it with function member address. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions

Comment: @KerrekSB [Why not?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/990625/c-function-pointer-class-member-to-non-static-member-function)

Comment: Why don't you just make a bunch of non-member functions that forward to the member functions, and take the address of those?

Comment: Use std::function from C++11.

Comment: @Mankarse That would, at least, give him a hint of why it cannot work.

Comment: None of the solutions you propose will actually give you anything usable.

Comment: It does not throw any compiling error. I have re-tested again my results by all methods and the function **printf**. And no errors have been found.

Comment: @xersi: Just testing alone cannot guarantee the correctness of your code. You can't convert pointers to member functions to `void*` because [pointers to member functions can have a size bigger than `sizeof(void*)`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/02/09/70002.aspx). That fact alone makes stuffing pointers to member functions into `void*` a non-starter.

Comment: With that I am going to do some research. For example I think **virtual function** is just a normal function object, only it's partly related to the base function. EDIT : I know the size, but I have an evidence which can partly prove why my algorithm is correct (not sure)

Comment: @xersi: I'm sorry to say but you're missing the point. You can't just stuff any arbitrary member function pointer into a `void*` because there's no guarantee that the size of a member function pointer is less than or equal to `sizeof(void*)`. No such guarantee exists in order to allow compilers to generate useful member function pointers for all possible cases.

Comment: But my compiler does. Weird? I can freely call a member function with `void*` address by assembly and it runs properly without any error. :)

Comment: @xersi Irrelevant implementation details.

Comment: @xersi it doesn't mean it isn't UB

Comment: Well, hard to explain. I'll check again. And check whether 4-byte pointer or 8-byte pointer is correct or not...

Comment: @xersi You "check it" by reading the standard, not doing weird tricks in code. Implementation is not relevant here for anything

Comment: @Xersi You haven't actually tried to use the results of your conversion, at least not for anything non-trivial.  The conversions are all more or less legal, _but_ you've lost information, and cannot use the results in any way.

Comment: @xersi What compiler are you using.  For g++, the sizes are 4 and 8.  For VC++, 4 and 16.  (With VC++, of course, you have to use the option `/vmg`.  Otherwise, pointers to member functions don't work.

Comment: @xersi And I can guarantee that the results of your conversions _don't_ work with g++ or VC++.  If you are using one of these compilers, and they seem to work, you just haven't tested it sufficiently.

Answer (score 5):

Unless your compiler is broken, you can't directly convert any
function pointer, member of not, to `void*`.  On systems where
non-member function pointers have the same size and format as
non-member data pointers (required by Posix), you can do some
fancy type punning:

```
void (*fp)();
void * p = *reinterpret_cast<void**>( &fp );
```

This is undefined behavior according to the C++ standard, but
will work on most von Neumann machines with linear addressing.
(It is likely to do strange things on Harvard architectures, or
machines with non-linear addressing.)

This only works when the types (original and target) have
exactly the same size and format.  Pointers to member functions
require additional information, which means that they almost
never have the same size and format as normal function pointers,
let alone data pointers.

I might add that none of the methods you describe actually work, in the sense that you can use the results in any way.

Comment: So basically POSIX defines an UB in C++?

Comment: @H2CO3: It does. For example `dlsym` returns `void*` despite the fact that it returns the address of a function.

Comment: It is a regular function object. I am taking about function member (structure).

Comment: @Mankarse I know that, but I always thought it was UB even under POSIX.

Comment: @H2CO3 In some cases, yes.  In this case, all it's doing is restricting the possibilities of implementation defined behavior.

Comment: @H2CO3 Something like `(void (*)())dlsym(...)` is illegal, even in Posix, and a compliant C or C++ compiler is required to emit a diagnostic.  The example of `dlsym` use in the Posix standard is `*(void **)(&fptr) = dlsym(handle, "my_function");`, which is well defined _if_ `void*` and `int (*)(int)` (the type of `fptr`) have the same size and representation.  Which Posix requires.

Comment: @H2CO3: Why not -- UB means anything can happen, including well-defined behaviour under some additional guarantees. Posix chooses to provide such guarantees for this behaviour. It's legal under C++ to behave well.

Answer (score 0):

A pointer to member function can be cast to another pointer to member function type (per 5.2.10p10).  So, instead of `void *`, use `void (*X::)()` for some placeholder user-defined type X:

```
struct X;
typedef void (*X::mem_fun_ptr_t)();

mem_fun_ptr_t mem_fun_ptr = reinterpret_cast<mem_fun_ptr_t>(&FOO::ONE_PARAM);
mem_fun_ptr_t mem_fun_ptr = reinterpret_cast<mem_fun_ptr_t>(&FOO::TWO_PARAM);
mem_fun_ptr_t mem_fun_ptr = reinterpret_cast<mem_fun_ptr_t>(&FOO::THREE_PARAM);
mem_fun_ptr_t mem_fun_ptr = reinterpret_cast<mem_fun_ptr_t>(&FOO::FOUR_PARAM);
```

Whether this is useful depends on what you're planning to do with the cast pointer; you can't call it without knowing the original type to cast it back to.

Comment: @ ecatmur - Is it conflict if I want to merge all database (**all standard functions** with all member functions from different classes & structures)? I have to use `void*`, `unsigned int`, or anything else?

Comment: @xersi what problem are you actually trying to solve? Why do you want to hold member function pointers in the same type as a function pointer?

Comment: Just I am going to make a generic structure like this `struct {void * address; DWORD code; unsigned struct_ID; PARAMETER_INFO param_info;};` - It holds the address of a function in general, and that's why I want to keep `void*` or `unsigned int`.

Comment: @xersi there's no such thing as the address of a function in general.  What are you planning to do with `address`: call it, use it as a tag, use it as a key?