# Redirecting stdout to LCD: pointer of member class

Tags: c++, avr

```
    FILE *LCD_stdout = new FILE();
    int (*ptr)(char, FILE *) = ROBOT::__LCD_putchar;
    fdev_setup_stream(LCD_stdout, ptr, NULL, _FDEV_SETUP_WRITE );
    stdout = LCD_stdout;
```

gives me error:

```
In member function 'SUBSYS_OPENSTAT ROBOT::LCD_open()':
LCD.cpp:108: error: argument of type 'int (ROBOT::)(char, __file*)' does not match 'int (*)(char, __file*)'
```

I've looked at a number of solutions through Stack Overflow and whatnot. .* doesn't resolve it, tried assigning a pointer of a pointer, and I feel I'm likely not going to be resolve it without resolving misconceptions.

Comment: You are trying to pass a pointer to a member function rather than a pointer to a free function. Make __LDC_putchar `static` if possible.

Comment: Making it static gave me an invalid use of static member.

Comment: Just realized I might be able to make the entire thing static... compiled, but realized it's not uploading to the MCU so trying to fix that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler error tells you **exactly** what's wrong:

> argument of **type** `'int (ROBOT::)(char, __file*)'` **does not match** `'int (*)(char, __file*)`

...because pointers to member functions aren't compatible with pointers to non-member functions, [for a couple of reasons.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/990625/c-function-pointer-class-member-to-non-static-member-function)

Comment: Obviously I know what's wrong. How do I get the pointer of a class member, as for a MCU to redirect stdout for the printf function (which is used heavily in the code I'm porting). I can't create an object as the object will be created to utilize these functions.

Comment: @Demortes You can't, there's no way a pointer-to-member can be converted to a pointer-to-non-member.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to create a separate free function but this depends on where the ROBOT object resides. For example if you have a global ROBOT object you could do the following

```
ROBOT globalRobot;
int callback(char c, FILE* f)
{
    return globalRobot.__LCD_putchar(c, f);
}

FILE *LCD_stdout = new FILE();
fdev_setup_stream(LCD_stdout, callback, NULL, _FDEV_SETUP_WRITE );
stdout = LCD_stdout;
```

If there is only going to be one robot object and it is a member variable of another class change `globalRobot` to be a pointer and set it after the ROBOT object has been created (ROBOT's constructor maybe)

This is untested as I don't know the innards of ROBOT but everything looks ok.