# Creating a thread in NachOS using a C++ class

Tags: c++, nachos

```
class Producer
{
public:

Producer(){
}
void Shout(){
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
        printf("I am a producer!!\n");
    }

}
};

void ThreadTest()
{
    void (Producer::* ptfptr) () = &Producer::Shout;
    Producer prod;
    (prod.*ptfptr) ();

    Thread *pt = new Thread("producer");
    pt->Fork((prod.*ptfptr)(),0);
}
```

I am trying to create a producer thread in nachos and and for that i am creating a class `Producer` (necessary for my assignment).  I have a non-static member function `Shout()` in the class declaration, and I used the above code to create and use the function pointer to the `Shout()` method.  The compiler gives me "invalid use of non-static member function".  Where is the mistake here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't say which line the compiler is complaining about, but I'm going to guess that it's this one:

```
void (Producer::* ptfptr) () = &Producer::Shout;
```

Here you are creating a function pointer using the address of a non-static function.  Non-static functions need an object to operate on, and you don't have an object yet.

Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/990625/c-function-pointer-class-member-to-non-static-member-function) and its top answer for a good example of how to do what you're looking for.