# Visual Studio 'non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member'

Tags: c++, visual-studio, function, class, pointers

I was trying to call a function with a function pointer where the function pointer is a class member.

I simplifed the code to only showcase the problem but the `foo()` function in the oiginal code is already writen so I cannot change it.

(In my actual code, `foo` is from GLFW (`glfwSetKeyCallback`) and `A` is an input handler class.)

The code is:

```
    #include <iostream>

    // this four line can not be changed
    typedef void(*fptr)(int);
    void foo(fptr f) {
        f(0);
    }

    void testOutA(int i) {
    }

    class A {
    public:
        void testInA(int i) {
        }
    };

    int main()
    {
        foo(testOutA); // works fine as it should be

        A * a = new A();

        foo(a->testInA); // ERROR

        return 0;
    }
```

The compilation error message is:

> ERROR: error C3867: 'A::testInA': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: Did you try using `&` to create a pointer to member, like the error says?

Comment: well I tryed to add & but I don't know where to add it so far I tryed the following ones but these where obviously wrong: 
&a->testInA, a->&testInA, &(a->testInA)

Comment: It won't work that way. What version of C++ do you have available?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *type* of the expression `a->testInA` is a pointer to a non-`static` member function.

It does not have the same type as `fptr`, so the compiler emits an error, albeit a cryptic one.

Compilation would pass if `testInA` were `static`.

See [C++ function pointer (class member) to non-static member function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/990625/c-function-pointer-class-member-to-non-static-member-function) for more details.