# Call class method non-static initialised by pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, c++14, memory-address

I'm trying call a method initialised by pointer to a method of other class, i've followed [this:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/990625/c-function-pointer-class-member-to-non-static-member-function)
but it has not worked for me.

consider this:

```
class y
{
    public:
        int GetValue(int z)
        {
            return 4 * z;
        }
};


class hooky
{
    public:     
        int(hooky::*HookGetValue)(int);
};


int(hooky::*HookGetValue)(int) = (int(hooky::*)(int))0x0; // memory address or &y::GetValue;



int main()
{
    hooky h; // instance
    cout << h.*HookGetValue(4) << endl; // error
    return 0;
}
```

the error that produces is:

> [Error] must use '.*' or '->*' to call pointer-to-member function in
>   'HookGetValue (...)', e.g. '(... ->* HookGetValue) (...)'

Comment: I guess you should write `(h.*HookGetValue)(4)` instead?

Comment: @AdrianShum thanks a lot, but why works? please you can tell me?, I do not understand if is the same.

Comment: check my update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct syntax to invoke a member function pointer is

```
(h.*HookGetValue)(4)
```

---

Update: the reason original code does not work as expected is because of operator precedence of C++: function invocation `()` is having higher precedence than ptr to member `.*`.  Which means

```
h.*HookGetValue(4)
```

will be see as

```
h.*(HookGetValue(4))
```