# How to define and set a funtion pointer to a template class method

Tags: c++, templates, pointer-to-member

I need to set a function pointer variable which is a method of a template class X to a method of X.

Here is a simple example.

**X.h**:

```
template<typename T>
class X {
public:
    typedef T (*valproc)(T v);

    X(T v);

    T add(T v);
    T val;
    valproc curproc;
};
```

**X.cpp**:

```
#include  "X.h"

template<typename T>
X<T>::X(T v) : val(v) {
    curproc = &X<T>::add;
}

template<typename T>
T X<T>::add(T v) {
    return v+val;
}

int main (int iArgC, char *apArgV[]) {
    X<int> *p = new X<int>(3);

    return  p->curproc(7);
}
```

When I compile this, I get an error:

```
$ g++ -c -g -Wall X.cpp
X.cpp: In instantiation of 'X<T>::X(T) [with T = int]':
X.cpp:15:29:   required from here
X.cpp:5:13: error: cannot convert 'int (X<int>::*)(int)' to 'X<int>::valproc {aka int (*)(int)}' in assignment
     curproc = &X<T>::add;
```

Apparently

```
int (X< int >::* )(int)
```

is not the same as

```
int (*)(int)
```

How can I define the correct type?

Answer (score 2):

`X<int>::add` is a non-static member function.  That means that `&X<int>::add` has the type `int(X<int>::*)(int)`: pointer to non static member function of `X<int>` taking a single `int` parameter and returning `int`.  Such a pointer cannot be converted to `int(*)(int)`.

`int(X<int>::*)(int)` is conceptually more similar to `int(*)(X<int>*, int)` than it is to `int(*)(int)` (though the implementation may actually be much different depending on the platform's calling convention or if [inheritance is involved](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040209-00/?p=40713)).  It requires an extra hidden `X<int>*` parameter: the `this` pointer.

The easiest way to do what you want would be to use a wrapper method:

```
template<typename T>
class X {
public:
    using valproc = T(X::*)(T v);

    X(T v)
        : val{v},
          proc{&X::add}
    {}

    T add(T v) { return v + val; }
    T curproc(T v) { return (this->*proc)(v); }

    T val;
    valproc proc;
};
```

[Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ebe356747e7ceccf)

The funky syntax `(this->*proc)(i)` says "call the member function pointed to by `proc` on the object pointed to by `this` with the parameter `i`".

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>

template<typename T>
class X {
public:
    X(T v);
    T add(T v);
    T val;
    int (X::*curproc)(T v);
};

template<typename T>
X<T>::X(T v) : val(v) {
    curproc = &X<T>::add;
}

template<typename T>
T X<T>::add(T v) {
    return v+val;
}

int main()
{
    printf("Hello World\n");
    X<int> *p = new X<int>(3);

    printf("%d\n",  (p->*(p->curproc))(7));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Usualy template classes are defined in the header file.
You can find more information here:

- [Why can’t I separate the definition of my templates class from its declaration and put it inside a .cpp file?](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/templates#templates-defn-vs-decl)
- [How can I avoid linker errors with my template functions?](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/templates#separate-template-fn-defn-from-decl)
- [How does the C++ keyword export help with template linker errors?](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/templates#separate-template-fn-defn-from-decl-export-keyword)

Comment: this is relevant, but does not adress the issue with member function pointers

Comment: When i put the entire code of my  class into the headerfile, i get the same compiler error

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
return  p->curproc(7);
```

to

```
return (p->*(p->curproc))(7);
```

*(p->currproc) is the function pointer and that need to be called on p object pointer

For details

[C++ function pointer (class member) to non-static member function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/990625/c-function-pointer-class-member-to-non-static-member-function?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)